# Memory management for Strassen's matrix multiplication

Tags: c, memory-management, matrix, strassen

As a part of an assignment, I am trying to find out the crossover point for Strassen's matrix multiplication and naive multiplication algorithms. But for the same, I am unable to proceed when matrix becomes 256x256. Can someone please suggest me the appropriate memory management technique to be able to handle larger inputs.

The code is in C as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

void strassenMul(double* X, double* Y, double* Z, int m);
void matMul(double* A, double* B, double* C, int n);
void matAdd(double* A, double* B, double* C, int m);
void matSub(double* A, double* B, double* C, int m);

int idx = 0;

int main()
{
    int N;
    int count = 0;
    int i, j;
    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;

    int total = 15;
    double tnaive[total];
    double tstrassen[total];
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    for (count = 0; count < total; count++)
    {
        N = pow(2, count);
        printf("Matrix size = %2d\t",N);
        double X[N][N], Y[N][N], Z[N][N], W[N][N];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                X[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
                Y[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
            }
        }
        start = clock();
        matMul((double *)X, (double *)Y, (double *)W, N);
        end = clock();
        elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        tnaive[count] = elapsed;
        printf("naive = %5.4f\t\t",tnaive[count]);

        start = clock();
        strassenMul((double *)X, (double *)Y, (double *)Z, N);
        end = clock();
        elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        tstrassen[count] = elapsed;
        printf("strassen = %5.4f\n",tstrassen[count]);
    }
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");

    while (tnaive[idx+1] <= tstrassen[idx+1] && idx < 14) idx++;

    printf("Optimum input size to switch from normal multiplication to Strassen's is above %d\n\n", idx);

    printf("Please enter the size of array as a power of 2\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    double A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
            B[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
        }
    }

printf("------------------- Input Matrices A and B ---------------------------\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",A[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",B[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n------- Output matrix by Strassen's method after optimization -----------\n\n");

    strassenMul((double *)A, (double *)B, (double *)C, N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",C[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}

void strassenMul(double *X, double *Y, double *Z, int m)
{
    if (m <= idx)
    {
        matMul((double *)X, (double *)Y, (double *)Z, m);
        return;
    }
    if (m == 1)
    {
        *Z = *X * *Y;
        return;
    }
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    int n = m/2;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double x11[n][n], x12[n][n], x21[n][n], x22[n][n];
    double y11[n][n], y12[n][n], y21[n][n], y22[n][n];
    double P1[n][n], P2[n][n], P3[n][n], P4[n][n], P5[n][n], P6[n][n], P7[n][n];
    double C11[n][n], C12[n][n], C21[n][n], C22[n][n];
    double S1[n][n], S2[n][n], S3[n][n], S4[n][n], S5[n][n], S6[n][n], S7[n][n];
    double S8[n][n], S9[n][n], S10[n][n], S11[n][n], S12[n][n], S13[n][n], S14[n][n];

    for (row = 0, i = 0; row < n; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
        {
            x11[i][j] = *((X+row*m)+col);
            y11[i][j] = *((Y+row*m)+col);
        }
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
        {
            x12[i][j] = *((X+row*m)+col);
            y12[i][j] = *((Y+row*m)+col);
        }
    }

    for (row = n, i = 0; row < m; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
        {
            x21[i][j] = *((X+row*m)+col);
            y21[i][j] = *((Y+row*m)+col);
        }
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
        {
            x22[i][j] = *((X+row*m)+col);
            y22[i][j] = *((Y+row*m)+col);
        }
    }

    // Calculating P1
    matAdd((double *)x11, (double *)x22, (double *)S1, n);
    matAdd((double *)y11, (double *)y22, (double *)S2, n);
    strassenMul((double *)S1, (double *)S2, (double *)P1, n);

    // Calculating P2
    matAdd((double *)x21, (double *)x22, (double *)S3, n);
    strassenMul((double *)S3, (double *)y11, (double *)P2, n);

    // Calculating P3
    matSub((double *)y12, (double *)y22, (double *)S4, n);
    strassenMul((double *)x11, (double *)S4, (double *)P3, n);

    // Calculating P4
    matSub((double *)y21, (double *)y11, (double *)S5, n);
    strassenMul((double *)x22, (double *)S5, (double *)P4, n);

    // Calculating P5
    matAdd((double *)x11, (double *)x12, (double *)S6, n);
    strassenMul((double *)S6, (double *)y22, (double *)P5, n);

    // Calculating P6
    matSub((double *)x21, (double *)x11, (double *)S7, n);
    matAdd((double *)y11, (double *)y12, (double *)S8, n);
    strassenMul((double *)S7, (double *)S8, (double *)P6, n);

    // Calculating P7
    matSub((double *)x12, (double *)x22, (double *)S9, n);
    matAdd((double *)y21, (double *)y22, (double *)S10, n);
    strassenMul((double *)S9, (double *)S10, (double *)P7, n);

    // Calculating C11
    matAdd((double *)P1, (double *)P4, (double *)S11, n);
    matSub((double *)S11, (double *)P5, (double *)S12, n);
    matAdd((double *)S12, (double *)P7, (double *)C11, n);

    // Calculating C12
    matAdd((double *)P3, (double *)P5, (double *)C12, n);

    // Calculating C21
    matAdd((double *)P2, (double *)P4, (double *)C21, n);

    // Calculating C22
    matAdd((double *)P1, (double *)P3, (double *)S13, n);
    matSub((double *)S13, (double *)P2, (double *)S14, n);
    matAdd((double *)S14, (double *)P6, (double *)C22, n);

    for (row = 0, i = 0; row < n; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
            *((Z+row*m)+col) = C11[i][j];
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
            *((Z+row*m)+col) = C12[i][j];
    }
    for (row = n, i = 0; row < m; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
            *((Z+row*m)+col) = C21[i][j];
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
            *((Z+row*m)+col) = C22[i][j];
    }
}

void matMul(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, row = 0, col = 0;
    double sum;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                sum += *((A+i*n)+k) * *((B+k*n)+j);
            }
            *((C+i*n)+j) = sum;
        }
    }
}

void matAdd(double *A, double *B, double *C, int m)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < m; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < m; col++)
            *((C+row*m)+col) = *((A+row*m)+col) + *((B+row*m)+col);
}

void matSub(double *A, double *B, double *C, int m)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < m; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < m; col++)
            *((C+row*m)+col) = *((A+row*m)+col) - *((B+row*m)+col);
}
```

**Added later** If I try using malloc statements for memory assignment, the code is as follows. But the problem is that it stops after the naive matrix multiplication method and does not even proceed to the Strassen's method for N=1. It shows a prompt to close the program.

```
for (count = 0; count < total; count++)
{
    N = pow(2, count);
    printf("Matrix size = %2d\t",N);
    //double X[N][N], Y[N][N], Z[N][N], W[N][N];
    double **X, **Y, **Z, **W;
    X = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
    if (X == NULL){
        perror("Failed malloc() in X");
        return 1;
    }
    Y = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
            if (Y == NULL){
                perror("Failed malloc() in Y");
                return 1;
    }
    Z = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
            if (Z == NULL){
                perror("Failed malloc() in Z");
                return 1;
    }
    W = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
            if (W == NULL){
                perror("Failed malloc() in W");
                return 1;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        X[j] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
        if (X[j] == NULL){
            perror("Failed malloc() in X[j]");
            return 1;
        }
        Y[j] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
                    if (Y[j] == NULL){
                        perror("Failed malloc() in Y[j]");
                        return 1;
        }
        Z[j] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
                    if (Z[j] == NULL){
                        perror("Failed malloc() in Z[j]");
                        return 1;
        }
        W[j] = malloc(N * sizeof(double*));
                    if (W[j] == NULL){
                        perror("Failed malloc() in W[j]");
                        return 1;
        }
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            X[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
            Y[i][j] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
        }
    }
    start = clock();
    matMul((double *)X, (double *)Y, (double *)W, N);
    end = clock();
    elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    tnaive[count] = elapsed;
    printf("naive = %5.4f\t\t",tnaive[count]);

    start = clock();
    strassenMul((double *)X, (double *)Y, (double *)Z, N);
    end = clock();
    elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    tstrassen[count] = elapsed;
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        free(X[j]);
        free(Y[j]);
        free(Z[j]);
        free(W[j]);
    }

    free(X); free(Y); free(Z); free(W);

    printf("strassen = %5.4f\n",tstrassen[count]);
}
```

Comment: Are you using sparse matrices. Sparse Matrices can be huge (possibly bigger than memory in your system) but contain very little actual data (hence the sparse bit). In such a case you are probably better off storing you data in some sort of list where you store the datum together with the location of said datum in the matrix.

Comment: @doron Nope. No special case of sparse matrix.

Comment: @Neha ref your later added code showing how you `malloc()` and `free()` memory. You have released the memory for each column array correctly, but not the row pointers - which you freed in the loop `for (j=0; j<N; j++) { free(X); free(Y); free(Z); free(W);}`. Take out the loop - you only allocated `X` etc once.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed this error. Could you please do me one more favor? Could you please check if I am getting the recursion in strassenMul right, particularly the base case.

Comment: @Neha I can't focus on its detail, but two points: 1. In a recursive function you should pay *particular* attention to the termination conditions, your first two conditional tests might or might not prevent infinite recursion, I am unsure. 2. The function allocates another **33** 2-D arrays dependant on `N/2` on the stack! And in a recursive function, that is a **COMPLETE** no-no! BTW if you found my "answer" post helpful, please "accept" it - I get 15 cents.

Comment: @Weather Thanks for all your guidance till here.

Comment: @Neha your question was about techniques for reducing memory requirements. On looking through `strassenMul()` which has heavy memory demands there is redundancy. For example, you calculate the matrix `S3` but after using it to calculate `P2` it only clogs memory. If memory was obtained by `malloc()` it could be released at this point. Ditto `S4` etc. Take the memory you need, *when* you need it, then release it. Or it would be more efficient if you use a `#define` so you can re-use memory already allocated, without losing the sense of what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have re-written the answer. My previous answer which allocated memory row by row won't work, because OP has cast the 2-D arrays to 1-D arrays when passed to the functions. Here is my re-write of the code with some simplifications, such as keeping all the matrix arrays 1-dimensional.

I am unsure exactly what Strassen's method does, although the recursion halves the matrix dimensions. So I do wonder if the intention was to use `row*2` and `col*2` when accessing the arrays passed.

I hope the techniques are useful to you - even that it works! All the matrix arrays are now on the heap.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

#define total   4       //15

void strassenMul(double* X, double* Y, double* Z, int m);
void matMul(double* A, double* B, double* C, int n);
void matAdd(double* A, double* B, double* C, int m);
void matSub(double* A, double* B, double* C, int m);

enum array { x11, x12, x21, x22, y11, y12, y21, y22,
    P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, C11, C12, C21, C22,
    S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12, S13, S14, arrs };

int idx = 0;

int main()
{
    int N;
    int count = 0;
    int i, j;
    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;

    double tnaive[total];
    double tstrassen[total];
    double *X, *Y, *Z, *W, *A, *B, *C;

    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    for (count = 0; count < total; count++)
    {
        N = (int)pow(2, count);
        printf("Matrix size = %2d\t",N);
        X = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
        Y = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
        Z = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
        W = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
        if (X==NULL || Y==NULL || Z==NULL || W==NULL) {
            printf("Out of memory (1)\n");
            return 1;
        }
        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (i=0; i<N*N; i++)
        {
            X[i] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
            Y[i] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
        }
        start = clock();
        matMul(X, Y, W, N);
        end = clock();
        elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        tnaive[count] = elapsed;
        printf("naive = %5.4f\t\t",tnaive[count]);

        start = clock();
        strassenMul(X, Y, Z, N);
        free(W); 
        free(Z); 
        free(Y); 
        free(X); 
        end = clock();
        elapsed = ((double) (end - start))*100/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        tstrassen[count] = elapsed;
        printf("strassen = %5.4f\n",tstrassen[count]);
    }
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");

    while (tnaive[idx+1] <= tstrassen[idx+1] && idx < 14) idx++;

    printf("Optimum input size to switch from normal multiplication to Strassen's is above %d\n\n", idx);

    printf("Please enter the size of array as a power of 2\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    A = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
    B = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
    C = malloc(N*N*sizeof(double));
    if (A==NULL || B==NULL || C==NULL) {
        printf("Out of memory (2)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (i=0; i<N*N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
        B[i] = rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.);
    }

    printf("------------------- Input Matrices A and B ---------------------------\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",A[i*N+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",B[i*N+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n------- Output matrix by Strassen's method after optimization -----------\n\n");

    strassenMul(A, B, C, N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%5.4f  ",C[i*N+j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(C); 
    free(B); 
    free(A); 
    return(0);
}

void strassenMul(double *X, double *Y, double *Z, int m)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    int n = m/2;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double *arr[arrs];                      // each matrix mem ptr

    if (m <= idx)
    {
        matMul(X, Y, Z, m);
        return;
    }
    if (m == 1)
    {
        *Z = *X * *Y;
        return;
    }

    for (i=0; i<arrs; i++) {                // memory for arrays
        arr[i] = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Out of memory (1)\n");
            exit (1);                       // brutal
        }
    }

    for (row = 0, i = 0; row < n; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
        {
            arr[x11][i*n+j] = X[row*m+col];
            arr[y11][i*n+j] = Y[row*m+col];
        }
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
        {
            arr[x12][i*n+j] = X[row*m+col];
            arr[y12][i*n+j] = Y[row*m+col];
        }
    }

    for (row = n, i = 0; row < m; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
        {
            arr[x21][i*n+j] = X[row*m+col];
            arr[y21][i*n+j] = Y[row*m+col];
        }
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
        {
            arr[x22][i*n+j] = X[row*m+col];
            arr[y22][i*n+j] = Y[row*m+col];
        }
    }

    // Calculating P1
    matAdd(arr[x11], arr[x22], arr[S1], n);
    matAdd(arr[y11], arr[y22], arr[S2], n);
    strassenMul(arr[S1], arr[S2], arr[P1], n);

    // Calculating P2
    matAdd(arr[x21], arr[x22], arr[S3], n);
    strassenMul(arr[S3], arr[y11], arr[P2], n);

    // Calculating P3
    matSub(arr[y12], arr[y22], arr[S4], n);
    strassenMul(arr[x11], arr[S4], arr[P3], n);

    // Calculating P4
    matSub(arr[y21], arr[y11], arr[S5], n);
    strassenMul(arr[x22], arr[S5], arr[P4], n);

    // Calculating P5
    matAdd(arr[x11], arr[x12], arr[S6], n);
    strassenMul(arr[S6], arr[y22], arr[P5], n);

    // Calculating P6
    matSub(arr[x21], arr[x11], arr[S7], n);
    matAdd(arr[y11], arr[y12], arr[S8], n);
    strassenMul(arr[S7], arr[S8], arr[P6], n);

    // Calculating P7
    matSub(arr[x12], arr[x22], arr[S9], n);
    matAdd(arr[y21], arr[y22], arr[S10], n);
    strassenMul(arr[S9], arr[S10], arr[P7], n);

    // Calculating C11
    matAdd(arr[P1], arr[P4], arr[S11], n);
    matSub(arr[S11], arr[P5], arr[S12], n);
    matAdd(arr[S12], arr[P7], arr[C11], n);

    // Calculating C12
    matAdd(arr[P3], arr[P5], arr[C12], n);

    // Calculating C21
    matAdd(arr[P2], arr[P4], arr[C21], n);

    // Calculating C22
    matAdd(arr[P1], arr[P3], arr[S13], n);
    matSub(arr[S13], arr[P2], arr[S14], n);
    matAdd(arr[S14], arr[P6], arr[C22], n);

    for (row = 0, i = 0; row < n; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
            Z[row*m+col] = arr[C11][i*n+j];
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
            Z[row*m+col] = arr[C12][i*n+j];
    }
    for (row = n, i = 0; row < m; row++, i++)
    {
        for (col = 0, j = 0; col < n; col++, j++)
            Z[row*m+col] = arr[C21][i*n+j];
        for (col = n, j = 0; col < m; col++, j++)
            Z[row*m+col] = arr[C22][i*n+j];
    }

    for (i=0; i<arrs; i++)
        free (arr[i]);
}

void matMul(double *A, double *B, double *C, int n)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, row = 0, col = 0;
    double sum;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                sum += A[i*n+k] * B[k*n+j];
            }
            C[i*n+j] = sum;
        }
    }
}

void matAdd(double *A, double *B, double *C, int m)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < m; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < m; col++)
            C[row*m+col] = A[row*m+col] + B[row*m+col];
}

void matSub(double *A, double *B, double *C, int m)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < m; row++)
        for (col = 0; col < m; col++)
            C[row*m+col] = A[row*m+col] - B[row*m+col];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @<Weather Vane> for answering. When I try to implement your code, it works. Infact, I had earlier tried malloc() and then freeing the memory in my code but I do not know for what reasons, the program stops after calculating time with naive method for N = 1. The only difference was that you have pre-defined N in your code to be 512 whereas I did it using N = 2^count where count is in {0,15}. Does that create a problem?
Moreover, when I switch to the method I have used above, I was atleast able to reach 128x128 matrix and then the program stopped.

Comment: @Neha I have expanded my answer.

Comment: @Neha, the reason my first demo using `malloc()` fails when `N==1` or `N==2` is because I print the first and last 3 elements in each direction which is out of the array bounds.

Comment: @Neha have you even calculated how much memory is needed for the four 2-D `double` arrays when `count==15` i.e. `N==32768`? 32 GB!

Comment: thanks again. But perhaps, I could not make my problem clear in the last comment. When I use malloc for memory assignment in **my code**, the problem occurs and the code is unable to  go beyond N = 1. I am unable to figure out where is it possibly going wrong

Comment: I understand that 2^15 is very high but even if I was trying it for 2^10, it was not working. From your above explanation, I do understand the need of malloc to fetch memory space from heap but again, I am perhaps making some blunder so that with malloc, my code does not go beyond N = 1. I have also posted later the part of the code with memory assignment, if done with malloc.

Comment: @Neha 2^10 is 1024 which for those four arrays will need 32MB, probably won't get that on the stack. I got 2^12 on the heap requiring 512Mb on Win7 with 4Gb memory, but not 2^13 which would take 2Gb. As for the naive `N==1` I looked through your code but saw nothing except perhaps you are using `idx+1`, and, are you comparing the first trivial case with another that you haven't yet worked? Not looked through your latest edit yet.

Comment: I think I got the comparison right because it is out of the _for_ loop. After I calculate time with both the methods and store them in respective arrays, I have compared for each case.

Comment: @Neha I have rewitten my answer.

Comment: If only I could upvote it a million more times, thanks a ton! :)

Comment: I guess this code is not optimal. You always copy matrices A11, A12, A21, A22, B11, B12, B21, B22 but is more effective to just make a pointer to blocks of matrices A and B.